# Bootstrap panel collapse creating gaps

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I've got 2 columns, with 2 panels each. Each column is 50% (col-md-6) with 2 panels inside that have collapse capabilities. Collapse works fine, but the problem I'm having is that If I expand a panel, the bottom left div moves far too low and creates a massive gap between panel 1 and 3.

This is what happens when I expand panel 1. The gap between 1 and 3 has ALOT of whitespace for no reason. I can't seem to figure out a way to fix it.

```
panel1  |  panel 2
        |
        |  panel 4
        |
panel3  |
```

[**Bootply example**](http://www.bootply.com/130890)

Comment: There seem to be a lot of duplicate element IDs in your code, and that's never good

Comment: @wavemode Yeah it's pretty messy. Most of the ID's don't actually do anything though. They just exist so I can identify them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it may not look like it, this is what is actually happening. Panel three is pushed to the right, and 4 is pushed to a new line.

```
panel1  |  panel 2
        |
        |  panel 3
        |
panel4  |
```

You are missing `row` divs between your `container` and `col-sm-6`. This will prevent the columns from being pushed around.

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/130896)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> <!--ADD ROW-->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
          1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
          2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--END ROW-->

  <div class="row"><!--ADD ROW-->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
          3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
          4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--END ROW-->
</div>
```

EDIT: Or something like this....

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/130906)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
          1
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
          2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
          3
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
          4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixes empty gaps, which is what this issue is about, but creating rows will make it look bad if one of the panels has a lot of data inside it. Do you know of any way to get around this?

Comment: @Envious see my edit above, I think this is what you are looking for... This will only push the panel below it down, instead of the whole row.