# Bootstrap no vertical gap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a classic bootstrap layout like: http://uppix.com/f-Now5351398300161b58.png

and I want no vertical gap between items: http://uppix.com/f-Iwant5351394f00161b56.png

Thanks for any answers.

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="price">300 EUR</a>                
            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB03K48SB/assets/img/h-3.jpg"></a>
            <div class="caption">
              <h3><a href="#">Bulharsko, Primorsko</a></h3>
              <h4><a href="#">Penzión SIM</a> 
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star blank-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star blank-star"></i>
              </h4>
              <p class="info"><a href="#">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</a></p>
              <p><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 21.06.- 18.06. (8 dní)</p>
              <p><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i> All inclusive <span class="transport">Bratislava <i class="fa fa-plane"></i></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!--/span-->
        .
        .
        .
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're experiencing that same problem as the writer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142077/bootstrap-panel-collapse-creating-gaps/). It's actually an interesting phenomenon that makes it look like an element is being pushed *down*, but that's not the case.

Comment: I do not want this. I want this: http://uppix.com/f-this5351400800161b6e.png

Comment: The answer there shows that you need to divide the page into three 'column' elements.

Comment: oh I'm sorry, thanks you wavemode, I fix it

Answer (score -1):

You could assign the image a unique class and give it a negative top margin for example

```
   .MoveImageUp {
  margin-top: -150px;
}
```