# Migrate from Bootstrap 3.3.7 to Bootstrap 4: huge blank space at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Once I migrated from Bootstrap 3.3.7 to Bootstrap 4, this issue occurred:
It seems a part of the gap is form the `body` tag
[image]

And the other half is from the `html` tag
[image]

It seems there are huge gap between the footer and the bottom of the page

here is the bottom part of the source code:

```
   </div>
    <div id="wrap" class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>        
</main>
<nav id="bottomNav" class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-top">
        </div>
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 footer-bar-left">
                <span>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-none">                       
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</nav>     
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js/app")
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

I have no idea why there are spaces created.

What's more, the footer should stick to the screen bottom when user scrolls the pages. However, the nav function doesn't work, once we migrated to Bootstrap v4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you expect any sensible answers, you need to post a **complete** `code snippet` (HTML, CSS & JavaScript including CDN links) that allows *replicating your issue exactly*. Otherwise, any answers would be based on guesswork and you want to avoid that. Edit your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is straightforward. It is because we added 60px padding to the body tag. If we removed it, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know most of your HTML code I cannot effectively tell you what is not working, but I had a similar issue on weekend and I got a solution, I edited your code based on my thoughts how it would look like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <main>
            <div>
            </div>
            <div id="wrap" class="container body-content">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <nav id="bottomNav" class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="footer-top">
                </div>
                <div class="footer-bottom">
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 footer-bar-left">
                        <span>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-none">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js/app")
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

What did you need to do in order to fix the huge gap?

You must set all the info in a **container** and then create individuals **rows** per section.

I got an idea from here:

[Bootstrap panel collapse creating gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142077/bootstrap-panel-collapse-creating-gaps)

Hopefully, it fixes your problem too.